# Closed form for an integral involving an inverse square root and a cube

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I bumped into a curious integral, which has so far resisted all the attempts I made to find a closed-form solution (not that I am sure there is one to start with). Has anyone encountered a similar beast before and could provide me with some hints on where to start?
The integral is
$$
I(w)=\int_{\sigma(w)}dx\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-x^3)^2-w^2}}\ ,
$$
where $\sigma(w)=\{x\in [0,1]: (x-x^3)^2-w^2>0\}$. Many thanks in advance, folks.

Comment: I think that, even with special functions, there will not be any "closed" form.

Comment: Setting, in a first step $x=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}X$, which brings the inside of the square root to a form proportional to $4X^3-3X$, then setting, in a second step $X=\cos(\theta)$ in order to take advantage of the formula $\cos(3\theta)=4 \cos^3 \theta-3 \cos \theta $ ? The introduction of the Jacobian $d\theta.\sqrt{1-cos^2\theta}$ should lead to a sort of elliptic  integral of the Legendre form form $E(\theta,k)$ isn't it ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral